# Реализация классической игры крестики-нолики

Tags: jquery, css3, ajax, php

Добрый день! У меня возникла задача реализовать многопользовательские крестики-нолики в классическом виде на языке PHP с использованием JQuery, CSS3, AJAX, JSON по принципам MVC и ООП. Так вот вопрос у меня такой есть на JQuery какие-то удобные плагины позволяющие реализовать такую игру. 
Интересует следующее:

- Как реализовать нанесение аппликаций на изображение (например кресты которые пересекли диагональ перечёркнуты будут еще сплошной линией сверху и завершится игра)?
- Как будет происходить обработка событий щелчков на зоне свободного поля, для прорисовки последующего креста или кружка игрока (в базу будет заноситься эти данные и передаваться другому игроку2 за другим компьютером, что игрок1 походил)?
- Как отследить что игрок не закрыл браузер, что оба участника игры в игре (обработка также событий досрочного завершения игры кем-то, выход из браузера например)?

По ходу дела может еще возникнуть пара вопросов, но пока только это. Кто реализовал подобное отзовитесь, как можно эффективно и правильно реализовать такую игрушку без перезагрузок браузерного окна в режиме реального времени. Буду благодарен, за все советы, замечания и пожелания...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

крестики нолики -.- жжесть....

1) дивами и наложениями слоев друг на друга

2) способы реализации разные, либо на прямую либо через БД и будет стоять таймер который срабатывает каждую секунду и получает текущее поле.

3) так-же, либо прямое подключение к серверу по принципу клиент-сервер, либо черз БД. (тот таймер который срабатывает каждую секунду, будет передавать статус)

будут вопросы пиши в скайп - Manitikyl

Comment: таймер я так понимаю на JQuery будет, да? Например setInterval, который будет через определенные промежутки времени проверять базу данных на то, изменилось ли игровое поле или нет. Так понял?